# request.get removing object with undefined/[object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, missing-data

I am new to node.js and the way it handles API's.
I am using an API to get data that looks somewhat like this

```
{ total: 1,
  skip: 0,
  page_size: 10,
  buy: { total: 1, listings: [ [Object] ], fold: false },
  sell: []
}
```

in the buy.listings is supposed to be a large array with lots of stuff but it just seems to replace it with [Object]. If I directly plug in the URL it used it has the data shown.

This is my request code:

```
request.get({
    url: url,
    json: true,
}, (err, res, data) => {
    if(err){
        console.log("error: ", err);
    } else if (res.statusCode !== 200){
        console.log('Status: ', res.statusCode);
    } else {
        console.log(url);
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

I'm sorry if its some obvious issue, i'm brand new to node.js

Comment: Its not an issue, on console if content is too large to display it will print as `object`

Comment: try JSON.stringify in console.log( JSON.stringify(data)).

Answer (score 0):

It is normal, by default, when logging big objects, it will not expend all nested objects. If you want to log everything you can use util.inspect to log your object, this way :

```
const util = require('util');

console.log(util.inspect(data, false, null));
```